# Can I query and filter the child of a child directly in firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure looks like this:

[image]

I want to directly query all students that have a shiftId equal to "-Ljzo2N-....". Is this possible in firebase realtime database?

I thought of a query like
`ref.child('jobQueue').orderByChild('parameters/shiftId').equalTo('-Ljzo2N-......)` but not sure if it is the right approach

Comment: Answer below. If you're having trouble making it work, please edit your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the error or unexpected output you get.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `jobQueue` is the parent of `-Mrug...` then `ref.child('jobQueue').orderByChild('parameters/shiftId').equalTo('-Ljzo2N...')` is the correct way to query the `parameter/shiftId` value.