# AngularFireList filter by specific child key name

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angularfire

I have an object called Payments which have multiple house objects represented by their id.

Each house have their monthly payment objects, like the picture below:

[image]

With the function below, I get all the payments.

```
getPaymentsByMonthYear(monthYear: string): AngularFireList<IMonthlyPayments> {
   return this.db.list('/payments');
}
```

But I wish to filter and return only the inner objects called **012024**

Following the documentation `https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?hl=pt-br#listen_for_child_events`, I tried to query like below, without any success.

```
getPaymentsByMonthYear(monthYear: string): AngularFireList<IMonthlyPayments> {
  return this.db.list('/payments', (q) => q.orderByChild(monthYear).equalTo(monthYear));
}
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: You should be querying child of child which I don't think would be possible when you have a dynamic key for the first child. Just putting it here for some ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70534705/can-i-query-and-filter-the-child-of-a-child-directly-in-firebase-realtime-databa